# Bootstrap row: Aligning 3 columns on smaller screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 columns in one row in a fluid container (container-fluid). I have been trying to align them correctly on screen size changes for have not succeeded in aligning them on smaller screens.

What it looks on big screens:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
|   Left sidebar  |      Main      |  Right Sidebar |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

What it should look like on smaller screens:

```
----------------------------
|  Left Sidebar  |         |
------------------  Main   |
|  Right Sidebar |         |
----------------------------
```

What it looks like now:

```
----------------------------
|  Left Sidebar  |         |
------------------  Main   |
|                |         |
|                |         |
|                |         |
|                |         |
|                |         |
-----------------|---------|            
|  Right         |
------------------
```

Here is the bootply: http://www.bootply.com/XHv1LaZJrA. I would like to know how I can achieve the desired layout on smaller screens given the structure of my code.

Comment: I am having trouble putting together a quality single container that does this. But you could just make 2 containers, hide and show them on screen size change? If that sounds good I can try it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you kindly demonstrate via bootply?

Comment: I am waiting to see other answers that are better than mine, but currently mine is the only working answer.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt! I'll see how that works on the website. I'll accept anything that produces the desired layout. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say that this is the *best* answer out there for the problem, but it is a workout around. What I did here was create 2 separate containers, one that is seen on large devices and hidden on smaller devices, and one that is seen on smaller devices, but hidden on larger devices. I did it this way because the gap comes from `left` and `right` not sharing the same column.

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/1RHZg33NAX)

**Code:**

```
 <div class="container hidden-sm">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">left</h3>

                </div>
                <div class="panel-body"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">main</h3>
                  This is the body for main. Lonnnnnnn
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed 
                    do eiusmod 
                    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad 
                    minim veniam, 
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex 
                    ea commodo consequat. 
                    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
                    esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
                    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, 
                    sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."


                </div>
                <div class="panel-body"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">right</h3>

                </div>
                <div class="panel-body"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container hidden-lg">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">left</h3>

                </div>
                <div class="panel-body"></div>
            </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">right</h3>

                </div>
                <div class="panel-body"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">main</h3>
                  This is the body for main. Lonnnnnnn
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed 
                    do eiusmod 
                    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad 
                    minim veniam, 
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex 
                    ea commodo consequat. 
                    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
                    esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
                    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, 
                    sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."


                </div>
                <div class="panel-body"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Preview Large**
[image]

**Preview Small**
[image]

Comment: you have two layouts. all he has to do is change it for the right column not all of it!

Comment: @nolawipetros the way you proposed creates a gap. mine is currently the only way that works,

Comment: what i am saying is that your formula and thought process is correct. but to have 2 different layouts is overkill .. you might aswell load two different layouts. the gap in my layout can be adjusted via custom css